# How to create differenet instances of an object from a single class while iterating an array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, oop, doctrine

I have this array for doctrine to process many to many form and save it to db but my code is not working because only one instance of object is created and then rewritten when iterating through the array:

```
$i = '1';
foreach ($myarray as $key => $value) {
  foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
    $addressObject = new \Entities\Clientaddress();
    foreach ($value2 as $key3 => $value3) {
      $addressObject ->$key3 = $value3;
      $account->getAddresses()->add($addressObject);
      $this->em->persist($addressObject );
      $i = $i + '1';
}}}
```

If my approach is wrong what is the correct approach to create an object without defining it explicitly?

Comment: It looks like you are creating 1 object and then iterating through and re-writting. Perhaps you should create the object in the last nested loop.

Comment: Could you refactor your code, so its easier to understand for others? I see 3 nested `foreach` and variables `$value` to `$value3` and `$key` to `$key3`

Comment: Do we _need_ to understand exactly what he's doing? The problem is quite clear with a reference of a single object constantly getting changed instead of creating new objects....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create an array of those objects:

```
    $addressObject = array();
    $i = '1';
    foreach ($myarray as $key => $value) {
         foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {

             // create array of objects here
             $addressObject[$key2] = new \Entities\Clientaddress();

             foreach ($value2 as $key3 => $value3) {
                 $addressObject[$key2] ->$key3 = $value3;
                 $account->getAddresses()->add($addressObject[$key2]);
                 $this->em->persist($addressObject[$key2] );
                 $i = $i + '1';
             }
         }
    }
```

Comment: Quick optimise the `$i = $i + '1';` to `$i = 1;` and `++$i` (Don't let php do all the type conversions). You know you want to, slip it in there.

Answer (score 2):

You could just create a new one in the loop, seems 'cleaner' / more legible to the next coder, unless the constructor is quite a heavy one that doesn't need repeating. That would get my vote. If you want copies of objects, use `clone`:

```
  ....
  foreach ($value2 as $key3 => $value3) {
      $curAdress = clone $addressObject;
      $curAdress->$key3 = $value3;
      $account->getAddresses()->add($curAdress);
      $this->em->persist($curAdress);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your object in the final nested loop.

```
$i = '1';

 foreach ($myarray as $key => $value)
{ 
 foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2)
 { 
  foreach ($value2 as $key3 => $value3)
 {
   //create your object here
   $addressObject = new \Entities\Clientaddress();  
   $addressObject ->$key3 = $value3; 
   $account->getAddresses()->add($addressObject); 
   $this->em->persist($addressObject ); 
   $i = $i + '1'; 
  }
 }
}
```